# Make Bootstrap current tab active after a POST action in ASP.NET Core

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, bootstrap-tabs

In the following `ASP.NET MVC Core` View two different forms are used in each Bootstrap tab-pane. How can we make the tab in which the form was submitted active? **Note**: In real scenario there are more than two tabs. For brevity of this post I've included only two tabs.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1">Test Tab</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane in active">
    <form asp-controller="myController" asp-action="myAction1" method="post">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Some content.</p>
      <input type="submit" name="GO" value="Value1" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="Tab1" class="tab-pane">
    <form asp-controller="myController" asp-action="myAction2" method="post">
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Some content in here.</p>
      <input type="submit" name="GO" value="Value2" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this but probably the simplest is to pass a variable to the view using the view model and then apply the active class to the pane and the tab accordingly.

Comment: @Richard Suppose ViewModel has a variable `HomeTab` of type bool. How do I use this variable to apply active class to `<div id="home" class="tab-pane in active">`

Comment: Added an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class based on view model like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane @(Model.HomeTab ? " active" : "")">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your slick solution; otherwise, although I was able get the final result but I was doing a workaround to achieve what you've suggested as a one liner. Also, following your code I also did the same for corresponding tabs as follows: **class="@(Model.myTab ? "active" : "")"** (Note: myTab here is just a place holder for the sake of this post)